# Corrupting Tensor with Gaussian Noise based on a Variance / Stddev Matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, normal-distribution, noise

I have a CNN output mask (**`logits`**, *`shape = [batch, x, y, classes]`*) and a matrix (**`sigma`**) that assigns a stddev for Gaussian Noise to each logit (i.e. *`sigma.shape = [x, y, classes]`*). **I want to corrupt each logit with Gaussian noise based on it's corresponding sigma.** In tensorflow, I only found a Gaussian that works on scalars: [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal).

Hence I used loops, "computed" the noise for each logit separately (`mean = logit[b, x, y, c]`, `stddev = sigma[x, y, c]`) and used `tf.stack` to get back my 4-D Tensor. BUT: For a *`[1, 1024, 1024, 2]`* -Tensor this already takes ages (to the extent of "didn't finish"), which makes sense, I guess since it has to create and stack > 1 million tensor objects.
Anyway, I am pretty sure this is not the way to go...

But how should I do this? **Is there a `tf.random_normal` that allows working in higher dimensions?**

I know that `tf.random_normal` can return a more-dimensional Tensor with (arbitrary) `shape`, however that doesn't work for me since that applies the same stddev to each element (the mean doesn't matter since I could generate 0-mean noise and `tf.add()`).

*If it's relevant in any way: A compromise I could live with for now (to speed things up) would be to generate noise with stddev based on pixels only (not on class), i.e. *`sigma.shape = [x, y]`*. But that takes away only one loop and not the main problem (x*y).*

*Here the code for the "loop" approach. I tested it for small values (`[1, 8, 8, 2]`. I know I could leave out the `for b`-loop, but it's not the "meat" cost, the x*y computation is the real problem*:

```
logits = self.output_mask   # e.g. shape: [1, 1024, 1024, 2]
sigma = tf.ones(shape=[1024, 1024, 2], dtype=logits.dtype)  # dummy values, will be a learned parameter later

corrupted_logits_b = []
for b in range(logits.shape[0]):
    corrupted_logits_x = []
    for x in range(logits.shape[1]):
        corrupted_logits_y = []
        for y in range(logits.shape[2]):
            corrupted_logits_c = []
            for c in range(logits.shape[3]):
                # this is where the noise is computed
                # (added to the logit since mean = logit)
                corrupted_logit = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(logits[b, x, y, c]), 
                                                            mean=logits[b, x, y, c], 
                                                            stddev=sigma_val[x, y, c])
                # "values"/logit-tensors are appended to lists and
                # ... and stacked to form higher-dim tensors
                corrupted_logits_c.append(corrupted_logit)
            corrupted_logits_y.append(tf.stack(corrupted_logits_c, axis=-1))
        corrupted_logits_x.append(tf.stack(corrupted_logits_y))
    corrupted_logits_b.append(tf.stack(corrupted_logits_x))
corrupted_logits = tf.stack(corrupted_logits_b, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually found a good workaround using the circumstance that a normal distribution `N(0, 1)` ***multiplied by*** σ (sigma) is the same as a normal distribution ***with `stddev`*** σ (sigma) `N(0, σ**2)`:

```
N(0,σ**2) = N(0,1)⋅σ
```

Hence you can do:

```
# sigma can be of shape of logits or needs to be broadcastable
sigma = tf.Placeholder(shape=tf.shape(logits), dtype=logits.dtype)
def corrupt_logits(logits, sigma):
    # generate a normal distribution N(0,1) of desired shape (4D in my case)
    gaussian = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(logits), mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=logits.dtype)
    # turn into normal distribution N(0,σ**2) by multiplying with σ
    # since sigma is a 4D tensor of tf.shape(logits), it can "assign" an individual σ to each logit
    noise = tf.multiply(gaussian, sigma)
    # add zero-mean/stddev-σ noise to logits
    return tf.add(logits, noise)
```

This will be a lot better than doing it with for-loops and supports various variants since if sigma is the same for a certain dimension (e.g. only different for each x, y), it is automatically broadcasted over the other dimensions (e.g. batch_size, classes).